# How to replace ":abc,cde\t" to ",abc|cde" using regular expression in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of string like below:  (without quotes)

```
"<someother string without :>:abc\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>:abc,cde\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>:abc,efg,cde\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>:abc,cde\t<some other string without \t>"
```

Would like to convert them to:

```
"<someother string without :>|abc\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>|abc|cde\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>|abc|efg|cde\t<some other string without \t>"
"<someother string without :>|abc|cde\t<some other string without \t>"
```

I am wondering whether it is doable?

Thanks

Comment: Does your input ever contain commas that you don't want to replace? If not, this should be relatively simple: `(?<=>):|\b,\b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think you can do this with regex, unless you apply it multiple times. You could do this instead:

```
public static String convert(String s) {
    int start = s.indexOf(':') + 1;
    int end = s.indexOf('\t', start);

    return s.substring(0, start)
            + s.substring(start, end).replaceAll(",", "|")
            + s.substring(end, s.length());
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did in function instead of regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
public class T28Regex {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strings = { "<someother string without *>:abc\t<some other string without \t>",
            "<someother string without *>:abc,cde\t<some other string without \t>",
            "<someother string without *>:abc,efg,cde\t<some other string without \t>",
            "<someother string without *>:abc,cde\t<some other string without \t>" };

    for (String s : strings) {
        System.out.println(s.substring(0, s.indexOf(":")) + "|"
                + s.substring(s.indexOf(":") + 1, s.indexOf("\t", s.indexOf(":"))).replaceAll(",", "|")
                + s.substring(s.indexOf("\t", s.indexOf(":"))));
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I did in function instead of regular expression

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function Replace_(str ) {
  var patt = /(:)((([\w]*(,)?)){2,})(\\t<)/gi;
  var res = str.replace(patt, function($1,$2,$3){
  return $1.replace(/,/g, "|").replace(":", "|");
  });
return res;
}
```

[Check_W3Link](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G2HCAUU691UB)